# Determine all functions $f: \mathbb{Q^+} \to \mathbb{Q^+}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine all functions $f: \mathbb{Q^+} \to \mathbb{Q^+}$ such that $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$ and $f(x^3) = f(x)^3$ for every $x \in \mathbb{Q^+}$.

I think this one requires me to prove the linearity of the function. But I don't know where to start with. I only found that $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is integer.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x%2B1)%3Df(x)%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24f(x%5E3)%3Df(x)%5E3%24&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [Functional eq](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1203143p5924690) and [Function E](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1322952p7125920). Note there's also a few AoPS threads, as well as several questions here, for the related problem where the second condition is $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful tools. I will take a look at it.